# Setting PUBLIC_URL in different .env files (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am working on a project built with create-react-app using two homepage url (staging and production). To avoid the need to change homepage in package.json manually before deployment to staging or production, I tried to set a PUBLIC_URL environment variable in both my .env and .env.production files and I deleted homepage in package.json.

```
PUBLIC_URL=https://xxxxx.io/new-manager-staging
```

After reading the doc, I assumed it would set the homepage url during build time, but it does not seem to be the case.

Is there an other place to set PUBLIC_URL or an other way to have multiple homepages or to set homepage dynamically in package.json?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your project to read .env variables you will need first `dotenv npm module` and then you would read like `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` assuming in your .env file you have a variable with PUBLIC_URL

Comment: I can read environment variables, that's not the problem (I use dotenv as well). The problem is that when I delete homepage in package.json and use PUBLIC_URL instead so I can have a homepage for staging and a homepage for production, PUBLIC_URL isn't used as homepage, so basically I can't access my website.

Comment: this PUBLIC_URL is used where ?, I am unable to understand where you are using this variable

Comment: I set it in the .env and the .env.production files.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly you are unable to read the variables from .env.production ?

Comment: No, I can read them. To me it seems that I can't just use PUBLIC_URL instead of homepage in package.json, that's why I am asking if anyone else knows how to set homepage dynamically (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: oh!! got your point

Comment: The link to docs how to setup .env files has moved here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. I needed to do `PUBLIC_URL=/new-manager-staging/` instead of `PUBLIC_URL=https://xxxxx.io/new-manager-staging`.